# JSF/Primefaces/PrettyFaces - do action everytime button or link is being clicked

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

What shall I implement to do certain action whenever button/link is clicked?
I want to save every URL of the page that button is clicked to make a history of pages.

Answer (score 1):

Well,
I come up with following idea: implement custom Navigator with forward & redirect methods which will put pretty faces IDs to history stack. Call navigator's method when using link, call navigator's method in regular beans, so every method's signature will be void.